# .net best way to render advance forms?

Tags: html, .net, wpf, forms, winforms

I plan on making an advance form system cms for company use. The options I found are WPF, winforms or to render it in HTML on an offline application.

I have varying level of experience with the first 2 but the third one I never came across until recently while researching this topic but (unless I'm poorly searching for it) I can not seem to find much info for it. I also need this system to dynamically create each form via code.

My question is for my situation, which would you choose and also explain a little more about HTML rendering method and how to create this type of system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We aren't building your system so can't advise what you should do

**Winforms**

Pros

- Classic structure so easy to pick up if you are familiar with classic desktop development

Cons

- Rigid structure controls functions and appearance are closely coupled meaning doing anything none standard is difficult

**WPF**

Pros

- Loosely Coupled function and appearance, this means that you can customise pretty much every element of the controls similar to CSS
- High automation level, binding is built in as a fundamental function

Cons

- very different to Classic structure as MVVM style is almost required, trying to do anything with out it is a very bad idea, meaning it can be hard to pick up

**HTML**

Pro

- Easy to build for anyone familiar with Web development

Con

- HTML is designed to be used online this means that any offline html system will require you to reinvent the wheel to circumvent the normal online behaviour (if you go down this route I would highly suggest an online intranet site rather than a offline system)

Comment: I would add: WPF best choice for Windows desktop.  Also need to consider UWP for WIndows implementation (for completeness).  For UWP, HTML/JavaScript (i.e. Cordova) a reasonable choice.

Comment: Best depends on circumstance, if they don't need styling and are happy with the limitations of winforms then that could be the best

Comment: Heavy design and animation should be in mind for this. Looks like WPF is the best for the project. Thanks!.